# Why does the javascript variable name only print once in this html?

Tags: javascript, html

When I execute the following code, why does the variable name which is assigned to output only print the first time I use it...not every time I used it?

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<script>
window.onload = function(){
    var name = prompt("What's your name?");
    var lengthOfName = name.length

    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = name;
};
</script>

</body>
</head>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1> <p id="output" </p>
<p>My first paragraph.</p> <p id="output" </p>
<p>My second paragraph.</p>
<p id="output" </p>

</body>
</html>
```

when i run it...this is the what it looks like

> My First Heading dodo bird
>
> My first paragraph.
>
> My second paragraph.

I would expect it to look like this

> My First Heading dodo bird
>
> My first paragraph. dodo bird
>
> My second paragraph. dodo bird

Comment: you didn't close your opening `<p>` tags.

Comment: html `id` is supposed to be unique across the entire document.

Comment: Element ids are unique by definition so `getElementById()` will always return first instance if they get duplicated

Comment: Also since the prompt only runs once on page load are you expecting persistence of previous entries when you reload the page? It's not clear what you mean by "only first time"

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Instead of `document.getElementById` use `document.querySelectorAll('#elID')`, and loop over all the elements, setting their innerhtml.

Although, you should use class instead, as each elements Id in a doc should be unique. So, `document.querySelectorAll('.elClass')`